# SonarCloud doesn't analyse Xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-devops, pipeline, sonarcloud

I have a solution in Xamarin stored in Azure devOps git repository. I've created a pipeline to analyse the code on SonarCloud. My Xamarin solution contain 3 projects (Xamarin forms, Xamarin Android, Xamarin iOS). Here is the pipeline:

[image: Pipeline image]

When I run the pipeline everything is OK (nuget restore, build, code analysis, publish) but when I go to SonarCloud, I see that only Android and iOS projects have been analysed. The Xamarin forms project was not analysed. In sonarCloud, I can see my code for the iOS and Android projects but not for my Xamarin forms project. Can somebody know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I understand why. It's because I've analysed a short lived branch. Only the new and modified files, compared to the “target branch”, are displayed and can contain issues.
By default branches are short-lived if their name does not start with “branch” nor “release”.